# Cocos2dx Android I'm broken phenomenon after the launch is an image sprite onResume Activity

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, onresume, onpause

```
CCTexture2D *t = new CCTexture2D();
t->initWithData(imageData, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888, sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsWide(), sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh(), sprite->getTexture()->getContentSize());

CCSprite *ret = CCSprite::createWithTexture(t);
```

In this way, only the title and sprite-like phenomenon is created.

CCSprite *ret  the effect of the water on the Beach the Sprite to customize the image.
IOS, Android, without any problems, the onPause ()-> onResume (a) through
Ret image turns black

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Any sprite that was not loaded from file becomes black after resuming, either CCTexture2D initialized with data or CCRenderTexture.

Easiest solution: stop using dynamic textures, load all textures from files.

Workaround: Resume event callback placed in your cocos2d::CCApplication subclass - it's method applicationWillEnterForeground(). You can manually reload all textures inside this method. For example, create own interface A that have virtual method to reload child textures, and manager class B which keeps global list of A. A registers itself in B in constructor and unregisters in destructor.

In each class that uses dynamic textures (i.e without file representation), implement interface A and override method in order to reload all dynamic textures.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same problem. You need to make changes in CCPlatformMacros.h, Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java and main.cpp( in you jni folder).

You should go throught this for detailed changes https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/2384.