# How to trigger function from main thread when the app is on resume state using cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want this method to be called inside of cocos2d::CCApplication applicationWillEnterForeground()

```
const char * HelloWorld::getUri(){
JavaVM *jvm; //this is important to avoid threading errors
thisEnv->GetJavaVM(&jvm); //this is important to avoid threading errors
jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&thisEnv, 0); //this is important to avoid threading errors
    //jstring jstr = thisEnv->NewStringUTF("From jni");
jclass cls = thisEnv->GetObjectClass(thisObj);
jmethodID method = thisEnv->GetMethodID(cls, "getPath","()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring result = (jstring)thisEnv->CallObjectMethod(thisObj, method);
    // call the sayHello() method
const char * string=thisEnv->GetStringUTFChars(result, 0);
//CCMessageBox(string,"Alert");
//if(string!=NULL){
    CCSprite* person = CCSprite::create(string);
        //person->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
    person->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, -.75));
    person->setPosition(ccp(0,0));
        this->addChild(person,204);

return string;
```

}

Comment: Why you need to call it inside `cocos2d::CCApplication applicationWillEnterForeground()`? Rather then messing with framework code you should call it inside `AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()` method. You need to keep reference of `HelloWorld` layer in `AppDelegate` to call any of method.

Comment: what i tried, i call getUri function inside of appdelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground(){HelloWorld hello; hello.getUri()} but implementing this I got an exception  call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread) whats wrong? can you help me ..thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726426/cocos2dx-android-im-broken-phenomenon-after-the-launch-is-an-image-sprite-onres I am referring to this question